# Questions about subalgebras of finitely generated $k$-algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Let $k$ be a field (if necessary assume $k$ to be algebraically closed). Let $A$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra and let $B$ be a subalgebra of $A$. Remark that $B$ doesn't have to be noetherian, let alone finitely generated (consider $A=k[x,y]$, $B=k[x,xy,xy^2,\dotsc]$).

**Question 1.** Does it follow that $\mathrm{dim}(B) \leq \dim(A)$?

This is true when $B$ is also finitely generated and $A$ is an integral domain. Because then we may use the expression of the dimension as the transcendence degree of the field of fractions. Is it also true when $B$ is not assumed to be finitely generated, or if $A$ is not an integral domain?

**Question 2.** Assume that $B$ is noetherian. Does it follow that $B$ is finitely generated?

Comment: Does $\dim$ here mean Krull dimension?

Answer (score 2):

$1.$ As I've mention [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110060/transcendence-degree-of-subring-of-polynomial-ring/110114#110114) if $A$ is a polynomial ring the answer to your question is yes.

If $A$ is an integral domain and $B$ is a $k$-subalgebra (not necessarily finitely generated) the answer is still yes. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79959/krull-dimension-less-or-equal-than-transcendence-degree).

If $A$ is not an integral domain, I can't see any reason to be true.

$2.$ In [this](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/hiroshima-mathematical-journal/volume-12/issue-2/On-Noetherian-subrings-of-an-affine-domain/10.32917/hmj/1206133756.full) paper the authors claim that for $\dim B>1$ noetherianity is not enough to imply that $B$ is affine. (But you know, they are japanese and japanese are very good in (counter)examples, so we can trust them.)